# Xcode4 with Mac OS X 10.4 SDK

Tags: macos, xcode4, powerpc

In the latest iteration of Xcode, Xcode 4.0, the 10.4 SDK is no longer included. However, I still need to support 10.4 and PowerPC builds.

I have installed latest Xcode 3.2.6 which still includes 10.4 support. Then I installed Xcode4. Has anyone found a simple way to "cheat" and get Xcode4 to use 3.2.6's SDKs?

Comment: PowerPC builds meaning fat (aka "universal") binaries, or PowerPC-only binaries?

Comment: Either way, Xcode 4 doesn't even support 10.5—there's no PowerPC support at all. From what I've read (but not confirmed) Xcode 4 uses a different SDK format from Xcode 3, so this is not possible.

Comment: @Nicholas, I think you're confusing the platforms it supports running on and the platforms it supports _targeting_, the latter being what the question is asking about.

Comment: Nope. This is documented in the Xcode release notes - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html - you can't use the Mac OS X 10.5 SDK with Xcode 4. You can still compile code for 10.5 on Intel using the 10.6 SDK, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we restore ppc/ppc64 as well as full 10.4/10.5 SDK support to Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I did :) [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4).

Answer (score -2):

XCode 4.0 supports deploying to Mac OS X 10.4 right out of the box, so you shouldn't have to do anything special.

For example, I created a project then selected the project and right there, there is a field called "Deployment Target" where you can select 10.4, 10.5 or 10.6. QED

Comment: But it will still uses SDK 10.6 and the original poster said he needs PowerPC builds. SDK 10.6 cannot be used for PPC builds, since SDK 10.6 only offers fat binaries with i386 and x86_64 code.

Comment: Additionally, as far as I know, there are binary incompatibilities between libraries. For example, as far as I know, C++ code compiled with GCC 4.2 is not binary compatible with the code compiled with GCC 4.0. So in this case, major issues are targeting *PowerPC* using *C++* code. Whatever Apple does when you choose Deployment Target still won't affect the issues of compatibility with GCC 4.0's libstdc++, and other 10.4-era libs.