# How can I install the OSX 10.4u SDK to support backwards compatible OSX builds?

Tags: xcode, macos

XCode 4 doesn't install 10.4u SDK but some builds require it.  How can I get and install it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Apple dropped 10.4 when releasing Xcode 4 (see [Xcode4 with Mac OS X 10.4 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283965/xcode4-with-mac-os-x-10-4-sdk#comment5957828_5283965)).

There is a workaround documented here: 
[How can we restore ppc/ppc64 as well as full 10.4/10.5 SDK support to Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1):

Phracker has compiled all the old SDKs from 10.1.5 to 10.11 on Github. https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs